# Couchbase - ® symbol appearing as ? symbol

Tags: c#, couchbase

When I am saving JSON document which contains **"®"** in one of the field's value turns into **"?"** characters on couchbase. This happens only when I post document through Sync Gateway. N1QL upcert takes it correctly. I assume it is related to an encoding but don't know how to setup it on sync gateway.

Below is code in c# to save data in couchbase

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
byte[] dataload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonData);
var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(dataload, 0, dataload.Length);
```

Comment: Please provide the relative code for **c# and sync API**

Comment: How are you rendering the symbol?  You may need to look at using the HTML Entity code... like &trade;  instead of the the actual character...  http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes/html-code-tm.htm

Answer (score 0):

There was in issue with the following line

```
byte[] dataload = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonData);
```

Replace ASCII with UTF8

```
byte[] dataload = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
```

And it worked fine.